# Can Team Foundation Server use https instead of http?

Tags: http, tfs, https

I am installing and using Team Foundation Server 2010 by following the book “Professional Team Foundation Server 2010”. The book says the protocol used in Team Foundation Server can be either http or https. However, I can only connect to my server via http, not https. How to configure Team Foundation Server so that it can support https as well?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you installing TFS 2010? It's unsupported and 8 years old. There have been **five** major releases since then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CAVEAT** I assume that you are installing TFS 2010 to simulate some existing environment and test configuration changes.
It makes no sense to use an unsupported 8 years-old version otherwise.
For real work one should use the latest version, TFS 2018 update 1 as I write.
If your organization is still using such old versions, I urge you to plan and implement migration.

Yes, you can and is explained in detail in [Setting up HTTPS with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer); the page lists TFS 2013 and 2015, but applies to 2010 as well (remember it is an unsupported version).

The basic idea is that TFS is a web app running in IIS, so you configure SSL in IIS and update a few IIS configuration values to use https URLs.